# what is the fastest way to import data into mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

Now I want to import a 10000000+ record table from database A mysql cluster to B mysql cluster,now I am using :

```
source xx.sql
```

It is so slow. Now what is the fastest way to import? I want to import like this:

1. import a new table,like `table_new`(it should be very fast like copy data,may be 1000000/s)
2. remame old `table` to `table_legacy`
3. rename `table_new` to `table`

4.add index or constaint if needed

is it possible or what is the best way to complete this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this blog can help you about how to quickly restore MySQL logical backups.[Click here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/02/22/restore-mysql-logical-backup-maximum-speed/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, 
[it would be preferable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/408311) 
to include the essential parts of the answer here, 
and provide the link for reference